# How to create rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How to create rails associations like this:
[image]

and example will show like this:
[image]

Comment: Your example isn't quite similar to what you are proposing.

Comment: question very simple and clear. Simply I don't understand how create association when 3 columns extend from one column in another table. What is the association should be with this two tables. has_many, has_one, belongs_to?

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume you have a `users` table first, and each `User` object `has_one` or `has_many` `skill_set` or `skill_sets` respectively.

```
Table Name: users
id first_name last_name address 
1  Arslan     Ali       ABC
2  Adnan      Saqib     ABC
3  Mahtab     Maqsood   ABC
```

And for table, `skill_sets`:

```
Table Name: skill_sets
id user_id dance_skill sing_skill model_skill
1  1       1           2          2
2  3       2           2          3
3  2       1           1          2
```

And, in Rails, you could model it like following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :skill_set # I'd go with one skill set per user
end

class SkillSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # So it'd have 'user_id' in it.
end
```

For migrations, I'd have something like:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.stirng first_name
      t.string last_name
      t.string address

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateSkillSets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :skill_sets do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.integer :dance_skill, null: false, default: 1
      t.integer :sing_skill,  null: false, default: 1
      t.integer :model_skill, null: false, default: 1
    end
  end
end
```

And I don't understand, why are you using the table `skills` if you all you have do is to store 3 rows. You can have something like the following in your model:

```
class SkillSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  SKILL_LEVEL = ["Good","Profi","Noob"]      

  def skill_level(number)
    SKILL_LEVEL[number-1] # Arrays are based on zero-index. 
  end

  # Now you can do user.skill_level(user.dance_skill)
  # Other way: You can 'enums' as well, but it is up to you. 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to built the association,and your question is very straightforward. Simply add a field `skill_id` in model `TypeSkill` rather `skill_model`.

And write a simple association into your models

In `Skill` modle

```
has_many :type_skills # based on you requirement has_many or has_one
```

In `TypeSkill` model

```
belongs_to :skill
```